# Unable to understand Raw IR Code

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, infrared, arduino-esp8266

I am working on an IR based remote control app using arduino. After a long exploration i found few Raw Ir codes, which looks like -

```
"IR": "40064,1,1,96,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1057,96,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1057,96,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,48,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,5128"
enter code here
```

And it's very sad that even after getting this code i am unable to understand this code, I am using this aruino library - https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

where for sending raw codes is like this -

```
void  IRsend::sendRaw (const unsigned int buf[],  unsigned int len,  unsigned int hz){
// Set IR carrier frequency
enableIROut(hz);

for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < len;  i++) {
    if (i & 1)  space(buf[i]) ;
    else        mark (buf[i]) ;
}

space(0);  // Always end with the LED off
}
```

Where buf is an array containing intervals in microseconds during which signal will be low or high.
But the IR code i got above isn't working, because i think it's not having the time intervals but something else. Any lead would be gracious.

Comment: is the IR LED pulsing the codes? (you can use a digital camera to check)

Comment: I was working on the same project this summer and I found that TSOP calibration is extremely crucial. Make sure you use the exact TSOP sensor for this experiment. I have noticed many times, the values that you copy from the serial monitor has problems. Good luck!

Comment: @marshmellooooooos, Thank you, I know it's not much reliable, but good for a trial. Bdw, i figured out a temporary solution for this.